# How to parse, and render, json for use in Django template

Tags: html, json, django, django-models, jinja2

I'm a newbie in Django and trying to learn, but I'm confused about how I can render data pulled from URL in a template in Django and display it in the HTML page.

The json data sample is:

```
{
"docs": 
[
  {
    "hostIP": "X.X.X.X",
    "time": "August 13, 2018 13:43:44",
    "site": 
    [
      {
        "site": "site1",
        "path": "/path/to/site1",
        "git_branch": "master",
        "git_commit_message": "New changes"
      },
      {
        "site": "site2",
        "path": "/path/to/site2",
        "git_branch": "master",
        "git_commit_message": "add card"
      }
    ]
}
]
```

}

Also how i can loop it using Jinja2? Please someone help me out of this.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Jinja2 rather than Django template language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view code, parse it with `json.loads()`:

```
import json

data = json.loads(my_json_data)
```

Then pass in `data` as a context variable to the view. Then you can see these variables and loop over them how you want in the template.

Comment: Thanks nnyby for the reply, in the view when I render it to the html file, there can I use jinja2 for looping and displaying outhe.